# Transform data before rendering it to template in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I want to return a single document with the fields joined together. That is, a result like as follows

```
{
  _id: "someid",
  name: "Odin",
  profile: {
    game: {
      _id: "gameid",
      name: "World of Warcraft"
    }
  }
}
```

I have a route controller which is fairly simple.

```
UserController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('users');
  },

  showAllUsers: function () {
    this.render('userList', {
      data: Meteor.users.find()
    })
  }
});
```

I've tried changing my data like so:

```
this.render('userList', { 
  data: Meteor.users.find().map(function (doc) {
    doc.profile.game = Games.findOne();
    return doc;
  })
});
```

However, this does not have the intended effect of adding "game" to the user. (and yes, `Games.findOne()` has a result)

How can you transform the results of a cursor in meteor and iron:router?

Comment: Couldn't you `fetch()` the results before mapping them?

Comment: I think if you do that, it will not live update (meteor specific thing). It needs a cursor to be returned if I am not mistaken. I've checked the cursor's `__proto__`, and there doesn't seem to be any transform type functions

Comment: Yeah, I think it will still live update, but it won't render nicely (entire set gets reloaded on template)

Comment: ah actually, the problem looks a bit different... I'm using _easy search_ which doesn't allow for transformation of documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your `data` as a function so it can be dynamically re-executed when needed.

```
UserController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('users');
  },
  showAllUsers: function () {
    this.render('userList', {
      data: function(){
        return Meteor.users.find().map(function (doc) {
          doc.profile.game = Games.findOne();
          return doc;
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your use of easy search, what might be simpler is just to define a template helper for `profile`

```
Template.userList.helpers({
  profile: function(){
    var game = Games.findOne({_id: this.gameId});
    return { game: { _id: game._id, name: game.name }};
  }
});
```

This assumes a single game per user. If you have more than one then you can iterate over a cursor of Games instead.